# Two points on curved path have a "gap" when stroke width is increased

Tags: adobe-indesign, path, stroke

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I don't really know what to search for. The issue is that I'm designing a "shield" emblem for my company, and I've done that by creating one half with the curves I like, then copy/pasting and mirroring it on the vertical axis. I brought the second side together with the first and when it was snapped into place I added them all together using the Pathfinder window.

The problem I'm having is that when I up the stroke width, the two points that intersect at the bottom are leaving a gap between them, presumably because the paths are on opposite angles. How can I fix this so that the stroke outlines match up nice and flush? You'll see what I mean in the below image:

[image: Two mirrored points that aren't "flush"]

The same thing happens when I have increased the stroke size on our corporate logo, but only in one place as shown in the next image:

[image]

Because this was for a print piece I used the pen tool and created this in InDesign, not Illustrator (CS5), but I believe I would have encountered the same issue regardless of the software.

Comment: @Ilan's answer is great, *for Illustrator*. I don't know that InDesign has the average and join capabilities though. You can join, but I don't think there's an "Average" command in InDesign. I, personally, would copy/paste the logo to Illustrator - fix things, and create an .ai file to be placed into InDesign. The "gap" is due to open ended paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solve this problem as follows:

Deselect all,

Press "A" to invoke Direct Selection tool and select 2 narrow anchor points which you want to connect -

[image]

Next, you make a right click and choose average and press Both in Popup:

[image]

[image]

This will place anchor points at the same location one above another:

[image]

Next, you join them -

[image]

Result -

[image]

Comment: On the Mac - Command-Option-Shift-J will average and join in 1 step.

Comment: Just read the question again... while this is fantastic for Illustrator. It won't work in InDesign. And my shortcut refers to Illustrator as well.

Comment: Should this same technique apply to the (designed by someone else) logo piece I've also shown?

Comment: @armadadrive yes, if you need to fix the art, you need to fix the art. The only way to correct that issue is to join the open paths. It doesn't matter who made that error. If it were a misspelled word you'd correct it.

Comment: Just wondered whether it was the same type of issue. I see it was, now. Thanks so much for the help, both of you. And for the record, I did copy it into Illustrator to make the corrections, but the procedure was bang on.